# Simple way to get the epoch of 12 AM for today in UTC in Python (3.x)?

Tags: python-3.x, unix-timestamp

I am trying to come up with the epoch of the start of the day (12AM midnight UTC) in Python. I found this snippet:

```
today = datetime.date.today()
time.mktime((today.year, today.month, today.day, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

but the resulting epoch leads to today's date at 5AM. The reason I need this is because I have a script executing a SQL command that needs to filter using epoch time (for some reason, casting or extracting an epoch through native SQL results in my query finishing in 5 minutes, as compared to 12 seconds). I'm guessing that the code snippet I put above uses my local machine time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to figure how what date it is currently in UTC, and then replace the time bits:

```py
now = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
midnight = now.replace(hour = 0, minute = 0, second = 0, microsecond = 0)
```

In order to get the epoch, use `midnight.timestamp()`. This will ensure that the timezone information is applied when calculating the timestamp.

Comment: Still seems to be giving me a 5AM epoch: 
time.mktime(midnight.timetuple()) = 1594011600.0
which is equivalent to 07/06/2020 @ 5:00am (UTC)



Edit: I'm sure this has something to do with my timezone, but I can't seem to see what's going on reading the time.mktime docs...

Comment: Don't use `mktime`, it's losing the tz info. Use `midnight.timestamp()`

Comment: Thank you! Looks like it solved my issue, epoch looks to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer above only works in a specific timezone. To obtain midnight of current timezone, I left timezone info blank and then got the correct timestamp:

```
from datetime import datetime

curr_time = datetime.now()
midnight = datetime.combine(curr_time, datetime.min.time())
midnight_time = int(midnight.timestamp())
```